# Python AsyncIO pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, io, async-await

I wrote a small snippet to implement asyncio `Pipeline` - object that connects together `Layers`, and lets them create and pass through objects. Each `Layer` could perform some IO to create/store an object or calculate something to create on object on the go or remove an object. `Layers` are connected with Queues, and they have states with Events triggered when that state changes.

The most questionable part was about how to let the entire process (I mean running the pipeline, not the system process) from any point in `Layer` or outside of Pipeline. That's what I want to get help (or recommendation) with.

[Original code snippet on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/iAnanich/f3cae79eaa4b913d0f4d38f95620365b)

P.S.: have plans of extending Pipeline so it will run multiple instances of exact layer concurrently. So it could have, let's say, 4 concurrent first layers and 16 concurrent second layers with a shared queue. But don't really know if I should create another question

**UPDATE**

- removed code from question

I implement concurrency inside layers by adding a new entity - Node. The project became too big even for a snippet, so I moved code into GitHub repository - https://github.com/iAnanich/aio_pipelines

Here I will post a bit modified code containing key components that could be improved, but an example of usage (currently there are 3 of them) can be found inside the `examples` folder of GitHub repository.

*1 - Pipeline*

```
class Pipeline(AbstractPipeline):  

    async def start(self) -> None:    
        self.state = STATES.RUNNING
        self.started_event.set()

        await self._run_layers()
        await self.stop()

    async def stop(self) -> None:
        async with self._finalizer_lock:
            if self.state == STATES.STOPPED:
                return

            self.state = STATES.GOING_TO_STOP
            self.going_to_stop_event.set()

            self._finalizer_task = asyncio.create_task(self._stop_layers())
            await self._finalizer_task

            self.state = STATES.STOPPED
            self.stopped_event.set()

    async def stop_at_event(self, event: asyncio.Event) -> None:
        await event.wait()
        await self.stop()

    async def _run_layers(self):
        async def gather_layers():
            await asyncio.gather(
                *[
                    layer.start() for layer in self.layers
                ],
                return_exceptions=True,
            )

        # schedule tasks for chain-like stop of the layers
        for idx in range(1, len(self.layers)):
            layer = self.layers[idx - 1]
            layer_to_stop = self.layers[idx]
            coro = layer_to_stop.stop_at_event(event=layer.stopped_event)
            asyncio.create_task(coro)

        # schedule task for stopping Pipeline after last Layer stopped
        asyncio.create_task(
            self.stop_at_event(self.layers[-1].stopped_event)
        )

        self._running_layers_task = asyncio.create_task(gather_layers())
        await self._running_layers_task

    async def _stop_layers(self):
        for layer in self.layers:
            await layer.stop()
        await self._running_layers_task
```

*2 - Layer*

```
class BaseLayer(AbstractLayer, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    class DEFAULT:
        QUEUE = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=0)

    def connect_next_layer(self, next_layer: 'Layer') -> None:
        self.next_layer = next_layer

    async def start(self) -> None:    
        self.state = STATES.RUNNING
        self.started_event.set()

        await self.before_start()
        await self._start_runner_task()
        await self.stop(join_queue=False)

    async def stop(self, join_queue: bool = True) -> None:
        async with self._finalizer_lock:
            if self.state == STATES.STOPPED:
                return

            self.state = STATES.GOING_TO_STOP
            self.going_to_stop_event.set()

            if join_queue:
                await self.queue.join()
            await self.before_stop()
            self._finalizer_task = asyncio.create_task(self._finish_runner_task())
            await self._finalizer_task

            self.state = STATES.STOPPED
            self.stopped_event.set()

    async def _start_runner_task(self) -> None:
        async def gather_nodes():
            await asyncio.gather(
                *(
                    node.start(layer=self)
                    for node in self.nodes
                ),
                return_exceptions=True,
            )

        asyncio.create_task(self.stop_at_event(
            event=self.aborting_event,
            join_queue=False,
        ))
        self._running_task = asyncio.create_task(gather_nodes())
        await self._running_task

    async def _finish_runner_task(self) -> None:
        for node in self.nodes:
            await node.stop()

        await self._running_task

    async def stop_at_event(self, event: asyncio.Event,
                            join_queue: bool = True) -> None:
        await event.wait()
        await self.stop(join_queue=join_queue)

    def abort(self) -> None:
        self.aborting_event.set()
```

*3 - Node*

```
class Node(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.event = OwnedEvent(owner=self, name='node task completed')
        self.task: asyncio.Task = None
        self.layer = None

    async def start(self, layer) -> None:
        self.layer = layer
        self.task = asyncio.create_task(
            coro=self.run(layer=layer),
        )
        await self.task
        self.event.set()

    async def stop(self) -> None:
        self.task.cancel()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def run(self, layer) -> None:
        pass
```

And again, my main question is about proper shut down of the pipeline from any point - so any Node might want to safely stop the pipeline, and pipeline could be stopped by something outside of it.

Although, any recommendation on how to make this implementation of pipeline more stable (it is stable, yet), clear and simple are very appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarity your phrase "4 concurrent first layers and 16 concurrent second layers"? Currently, the Pipeline connects layers in pairwise manner.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, you are right. Pipeline can't parallelize layers, yet. I meant that I plan to add such functionality soon. maybe that note was unrelated to main topic of the question, but I think that the mechanism of stopping the `Pipeline` with concurrent layers will be more complex than it is now and will need a review too.

Comment: Can you clarify the statement "*how to let the entire process (I mean running the pipeline, not the system process) from any point in Layer or outside of Pipeline.*"? It's not quite clear, as a Layer is inside a Pipeline and managed by that pipeline

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest for example, pipeline could be controlled by some message bus, which isn't represented by layer, but instead as a concurrent Task. Or any layer could stop the pipeline after retrieving some specific item from previous layer. `GOING_TO_STOP` state allows `Layer` to immediately stop item processing if needed, but it will continue working untill queue is processed by default.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I published an enhanced version on GitHub as [repository](https://github.com/iAnanich/aio_pipelines) - with concurrency implemented. Going to refactor a bit and edit original question here.

Comment: Ok, let me know after the question is edited

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest edited the question - removed old code, added the latest version with some additions, left the link to GitHub repo